# Enter key intermittently stops working on both my Macbook Pro's & external keyboard

Tags: keyboard

My Macbook Pro is 5 months old and I've started to get "enter" key failure on both my internal and external keyboards.
It works again when I restart the laptop. The fact that it's happening on both keyboards tells me that it's not a hardware issue per se.
I've cleaned both keyboards to make sure it wasn't due to a dirty underside of the keys.
Can anyone provide some guidance on this?

Answer (score 1):

It's very interesting that the external keyboard and internal keyboard are having issues with the same key. One action I also recommend when hardware like keyboards, back lighting, ports, chargers aren't working is to [reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) (System Management Controller).

In the meantime, let us know a little more information:

- Is the external keyboard wired or bluetooth?
- Is this issue *only* happening with the Enter key, and no other keys?
- Does the keyboard issue occur randomly, or have you noticed a pattern (like during certain apps, or when logging in, etc.)?
- Do you have Apple Care or any other warranty?